# Solution for transactional email

Tags: email, smtp

We have a small CRM that suppose to serve 10-20 customers.
Each customer needs his CRM to send auto emails (100 per day).
Some of our customers doe's even have a domain, they are using gmail / yahoo or maybe very very small and unknown email provider.

I need an SMTP solution that will allow me to send email in the name of the user, meaning that the `from` address will be for example `my.email@gmail.com` or `my.email@someotherhost.com` so the client can reply and get directly to their inbox.
I know that in SMTP protocol I can use whatever `from` address you want. but I assume that it would not be succeeded to enter the inbox.

Do you know such service?

Thanks